# How can I get the _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_ address in my program?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, x86-64

I want to get the address of _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_ in my program. One way is to use the [nm](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_nm.htm) command in Linux, maybe redirect the output to a file and parse that file to get address of _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_. However, that method seems to be quite inefficient. What are some more efficient methods of doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to work:

```
// test.c
#include <stdio.h>

extern void *_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_;

int main()
{
    printf("_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE = %p\n", &_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_);
    return 0;
}
```

In order to get consistent address of `_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_`, matching `nm`'s result, you will need to compile your code with `-fPIE` to do code-gen as if linking into a position-independent executable. (Otherwise you get a small integer like `0x2ed6` with `-fno-pie -no-pie`). The GCC default for most modern Linux distros is `-fPIE -pie`, which would make nm addresses be just offsets relative to an image base, and the runtime address be ASLRed.  (This is normally good for security, but you may not want it.)

```
$: gcc -fPIE -no-pie test.c -o test
```

It gives:

```
$ ./test
_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE = 0x6006d0
```

However, `nm` thinks different:

```
$ nm test | fgrep GLOBAL
0000000000600868 d _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
```

---

Or with a GCC too old to know about PIEs at all, let alone have it `-fPIE -pie` as the default, `-fpic` can work.

Comment: @MetallicPriest Perhaps you can tell *me* why `nm` gives a different value?

Comment: OK, when I'll check it I'll let you know :).

Comment: This code is definitely not right. You're printing the first entry of the GOT, which is probably a pointer to `DYNAMIC`, not the address of the GOT. To print the address of the GOT you should be using `&_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_`.

Comment: @trojanfoe just add the ampersand as R.. indicated, I believe that will fix it.

Comment: @ZeZNiQ thanks for your edit on this old answer, but normally (on modern Linux) `-fPIE -pie` is already the default so I thought I should tweak some.  I can confirm weirdness with `-fno-pie -no-pie`, like printing out `0x2ed6` for 64-bit mode, or `0x2e76` for `-m32`.  I don't fully understand that, so can you take a look at my edit and make sure I didn't mangle any important point you were making?

Answer (score 0):

If you use assembly language, you can get `_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_` address without `get_pc_thunk`.
It is tricky way. :)

Here is the sample code :

```
$ cat test.s

.global main
main:
 lea HEREIS, %eax   # Now %eax holds address of _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_      

.section .got
HEREIS:

$ gcc -o test test.s
```

This is available because `.got` section is adjacent to the `<.got.plt>`
Therefore the symbol `HEREIS` and `_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_` locate at same address.

*PS. You can check it works with objdump.*

```
Disassembly of section .got:

080495e8 <HEREIS-0x4>:
 80495e8:   00 00                   add    %al,(%eax)
    ...

Disassembly of section .got.plt:

080495ec <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_>:
 80495ec:   00 95 04 08 00 00       add    %dl,0x804(%ebp)
 80495f2:   00 00                   add    %al,(%eax)
 80495f4:   00 00                   add    %al,(%eax)
```

Comment: The question is tagged x86-64 so you can use RIP-relative addressing like `lea HEREIS(%rip), %rsi` / ... / call printf@plt.  Or just `_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_(%rip)`.  If you are going to use a 32-bit absolute address, though, always prefer `mov $HEREIS, %eax`.  LEA is pointless for static addresses except for RIP-relative.  (larger code-size to do the same thing with a [disp32] addressing mode)