# Get the address of __data_start symbol

Tags: c, linux, gcc, x86-64

I want to get the address of the `__data_start` symbol progammatically. For _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_, using `extern void* _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_` worked (See an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9686764/how-can-i-get-the-global-offset-table-address-in-my-program)). However, the same technique does not work for `__data_start`. Although the  compiler compiles the program fine, the value returned by the program is bogus. Any idea how this problem can be solved.

Comment: It didn't work; see my comment on your other question. And change `__data_start` to `&__data_start`.

Comment: @R.. Great! its works now! Thanks! Maybe you can put this as an answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magic symbols like `__data_start` are not pointer variables whose value is the address you want. It's the *address of the symbol* that you want. So you need the `&` operator, as in `&__data_start`.

Comment: Where is `__data_start` defined? Unlike `etext`, it's not on the linker script given by `ld -verbose`. But it is definitely the linker that defines it as it appears on the souce of `ld`. Some other linker scripts installed define `__data_start__`, but not `__data_start`.

Comment: Actually I have no idea. You'd have to check the linker source to figure it out, or ask someone who's an expert on GNU ld.

Comment: Sure, just in case it was obvious :-) If I find out I'll post back.

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
extern char _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_[];
extern char __data_start[];
```

(It is declaration of arrays, not of pointers!)

and use `&__data_start` in your code.

Comment: In this case the `&` is not necessary because the name of the array evaluates to a pointer to its first element.

Comment: Is `&` even valid on an array declared with an incomplete type (unknown size)? Normally the type of `&` applied to an array of type `T[N]` is of type `T(*)[N]`, but here there is no `N`...

Comment: Yes, of course taking the address of an array of unspecified dimension is valid.

Answer (score 1):

This code works with no problems at all.

```
extern void *data_start;
int main() {
fprintf(stdout,">%p\n", &data_start);
return 0;
}

atom :: » nm test | grep "data_start" ; ./test
0804a00c D __data_start
0804a00c W data_start
>0x804a00
```